# Margins and line spacings in moderncv

Tags: margins, moderncv

[image]

I have 2 issues with `moderncv`:

1. How to adjust the margins in the CV format.
2. Spacing issues with different sections.

I am new to `TeX` and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.3.26)  1 APR 2016 21:27
entering extended mode
**ENCV.tex
(ENCV.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncv.cls"
Document Class: moderncv 2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class

Comment: And can you help me how to do that? this is my second day of using MikTeX

Comment: start > programs > miktex > miktex update (admin)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your comment, you are using an old version of `moderncv`. Yours is version 1.5.1, the current one is 2.0.0.

Because I have only the current one installed I can show you only an MWE for the current version.  The current version uses different command names, that's at last your problem.

Before we can check where your problem comes from we need to have a MWE running on your and on my computer.  Please check the comments I added to my MWE naming the old commands you need to use.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
%\usepackage{fullpage} % <========================================= why?
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{5.6cm} % <==== old: makecvtitlenamewidth

%\firstname{xxxi} 
%\familyname{xxxx} % <=================== new command \name{first}{last}
\name{xxxi}{xxxx}
\address{ Vxxxxx\\ Txxxx, Ixxxx 1xxx\\} 
\mobile{(+xx) xxxxxxxxx} 
\email{xxxxxxx@live.com} 
\social[linkedin]{linkedin.com/in/xxxxxx} 
\photo[80pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle   % <====================================== old: \makecvtitle 

\section{Personal Statement } xxxx 
\section{Education} 
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
% <=========================================== Be careful: 6 {} needed!!
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}

\section{Education} 
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}

\end{document}
```

With this MWE I get the following result:

[image: Result of compiled MWE, version 2.0.0 moderncv]

In this result I can not see problems.

Please check my MWE, change it for your version and compare the result.  If there are differences, please add your used MWE to your question and the screenshot with marks were you have the problems.

Untested, because I have not installed version 1.5.1, but please test is on your system:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % version 1.5.1

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage{full page} % <================================= what's that?
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{5.6cm} % <=============== name changed

\firstname{xxxi} 
\familyname{xxxx} 
\address{ Vxxxxx\\ Txxxx, Ixxxx 1xxx\\} 
\mobile{(+xx) xxxxxxxxx} 
\email{xxxxxxx@live.com} 
\social[linkedin]{linkedin.com/in/xxxxxx} 
\photo[80pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a} % <================= from class MWE

\begin{document} 
\makecvtitle 

\section{Personal Statement } xxxx 
\section{Education} 
%\cventry{xxxx1} % <======== missing: {xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
% <=========================================== Be careful: 6 {} needed!!
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}

\section{Education} 
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}
\cventry{xxxx1}{xxxx2}{xxxx3}{xxxx4}{xxxx5}{xxxx6}

\end{document}
```

What should package `full page` do?  I guess it should be `fullpage`?